# Creating a form that has not been declared works - I don't know why

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm using Delphi 7 (I know it's antique) and am a bit confused by a form I'm creating as needed and destroying when done with it.

From my main form I create another form requesting a Username and Password. The newly created form properties etc are contained in a another unit and is included in the Uses clause.

In my main form I previously "had" the following code;

```
var
  MyOtherForm: TMyotherform;
Begin
  MyOtherForm := TMyotherform.create(Nil);

    { Then I do stuff - blah blah }

  MyOtherForm.free;
End;
```

My question is, when I remove the declaration for MyOtherForm in my main unit it still works without error.  For example;

```
{ var // removed
   MyOtherForm: TMyotherform; // removed }

Begin
  MyOtherForm := TMyotherform.create(Nil);

    { Then I do stuff }

  MyOtherForm.free;
End;
```

The same result, the form is created as usual and destroyed.  What I cannot understand is why. Have I been doing it wrong in the past by declaring my form in the main unit, or does having it declared in a separate unit sufficient?

Comment: Most likely `MyOtherForm` is declared as a global variable in the unit that contains `TMyotherform`. Afaik this happens per default when you add a new form to a project.

Comment: You have this variable declared somewhere else. [Search](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Find_in_Files) for it.

Comment: You have it somewhere in scope (we cant tell you where exactly). Use "Find declaration" feature.

Comment: It is declared only in the other unit and is not mentioned anywhere in any other file within the project. I'd say Sebastian is correct also, it is global in the unit containing it. I wasn't aware that was enough, thought it must be declared in the calling unit.

Comment: Re: doing it wrong - probably yes. If you use this variable elsewhere outside presented code, then you probably overwriting some meaningful data. If not - remove outer declaration, use narrowest scope possible - local one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Delphi creates a global variable for the form. It is added just below the class declaration of the form.

The name for that variable is the class name minus the 'T', so it's the same name you used for your local variable, which is why the code still works: you just stored a new reference in that global variable.

If you have an auto-create form, Delphi will create an instance of the form on start-up of the application, and store the reference in that global. You can manage auto-created forms and data modules in the project options, or you can simply edit the dpr file, in which you will find a line like:

```
Application.CreateForm(TMyotherform, Myotherform);
```

But even if your form is not auto-created, Delphi *still* adds that global variable.

Personally, I don't like those global variables at all, and I always remove them manually when I create a form or a data module. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a possibility to configure this.

So: Remove the global and declare the local variable like you did in your original code. That is the right way to do it. The global is there to make it easier for beginners, but it's not helping the maintainability of your application.

Comment: Best not to edit the dpr file. Delphi has a habit of undoing your changes to this file.

Comment: @GolezTrol, it isn't auto created and not in the project source at all. Yourself and Sebastian are mostly right, it is declared in the other unit and that appear sufficient. I've learnt something... I don't have to re-declare in the calling unit. Edit: I also remove auto created forms from project source and create forms as needed later.

Comment: No. Do redeclare it in the other unit. Remove the global variable. That only exists for the benefit of luring VB programmers to Delphi back in the 20th century, no longer relevant.

Comment: Do it the other way around. Remove the global declaration and declare the local variable in the calling unit. That way, you won't have trouble when you want to create multiple instances of the form, and you don't have to check in some global variable if it still contains an instance. Your original code was good. The global should be removed. I've rephrased my last paragraph to make that more clear. -edit- David says so too, so it must be right. ;o)

Comment: The **unit** variable (no such thing as globals in Delphi) is not *just* there for beginners.  It is also essential if you choose to AutoCreate the form since this produces code in the DPR that relies on the existence of that unit variable.  You might consider auto-created forms a "beginner" feature too, but that ain't necessarily so, especially in simpler applications where it is arguably a *productivity* feature.  You can't remove *all* such unit variables, *never* auto-create forms **and** never edit the DPR.  The two former *force* you to adopt the latter.

Comment: @Johan - the one part of the dpr that the IDE does leave alone is the   `Application.CreateForm(TfmXXXX, fmXXXX); ` section. But it _hates_ having them in conditional statements. No idea if this behaviour has been fixed in newer versions.

Comment: @Deltics [Embarcadero calls them 'global'](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Variables), but hey semantics. Maybe unit variables refers to variables declared in the implementation section. Those cannot be used for autocreate forms.

Comment: @Golez - Just because Embarcadero don't understand their own product doesn't make them right.  A global variable is a variable with *global scope*.  That is: in scope *everywhere*.  Variables declared in units have *unit scope*.  You can bring them *into* scope by *using* that unit, otherwise they are *not* in scope and therefore - *by definition* - are **not** global.  The one and only exception to this are unit variables in the `System` unit, since this unit is always and implicitly in scope.  Unit variables in other units are *not* global.  It's not "semantics", it's using the correct term.

Comment: @Golez ++ - w.r.t the Embarcadero documentation, consider this:  They say that "*variables declared in a function or procedure are sometimes called local while* **other** *variables are called global*" (my emphasis).  By this 'definition', member variables and *implementation unit variables* are also "global variables" which is patently absurd.  Just because whoever wrote that nonsense in the documentation got it wrong, doesn't make it right.  Slavishly making the same mistake and justifying it by pointing it to the original mistake doesn't fix it either.  ;)

Comment: Well call me an idiot (and I think you almost did), but I see this term being used everywhere throughout the webs, and me and every Delphi programmer around me also use the term global for 'unit' variables that are declared in the interface section. But hey, I'm only doing this for 20 years now. Maybe it's not *implicitly* in every scope, but at least you can bring them in scope, which is not even possible with unit local variables and local variables from functions and methods. In PHP you have to bring globals explicitly to local scope before you can use them, but they're still globals.

Comment: @Deltics But thanks for notifying me that the term may be wrong, but since the rest of the world uses it too and therefore knows what I mean, I kindly keep using it.

Comment: @Golez "The rest of the world" means something else entirely, when they say "global variables" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable).  In particular you might like to read the bit about "modular languages". The *actual* "rest of the world" sneers at Delphi enough as it is, yet the Delphi community (a tiny minority, certainly *not* "the rest of the world") seem to take some sort of pride in wrongly claiming to use Global Variables, even using demonstrably incorrect documentation to prove how "right" their wrongness is (you aren't the first).  btw. 22 years Delphi for me.  ;)

Comment: @Deltics You can invent your own terminology of you wish but don't tell us we are wrong when we use the official terminology of the language in question. Read the Wikipedia article. Tell me how a Python global is visible everywhere in the program.